# Raspberry pi 3b+ node app auto update and restart app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, raspberry-pi

I have using Raspberry pi 3b+ and node application need to check for latest version on site and update and restart the app. i will download the latest zip from remote and extract it , any solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thing by automation. For that you need some good skill in write a good script.

First of all you need to check that new version is there or not? For that I suggest to use **npm cheerio** or **npm nightmare**. This are node modules which helps your to scarab any web page. Using that you will be able to know the version update info.

Second thing , Once you got the version update = true , then you have to call one function which execute the list of process. Using above modules, you can click on button also. so you can download the file. then you have to execute script to install it and **restart app**.

Reference link for [cheerio](https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js)

reference link for [nightmare](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightmare)

I suggest to use **nightmare** as per your requirement.

Comment: can you provide me reference scripts for updating it

Comment: @VivekGupta Sorry for that. I don't know how to write it. You have to do some RND on that. :(

Comment: @VivekGupta In this case I just give you suggestion. :)